# PHP User gallery

Tags: php, sql-server, ftp, photo-gallery

I already have an idea for how to create mysql database for a user gallery... But  i have few questions:

Premise: i don't want to save photoes in a database for performance issue
I already tried to save photoes in a database but then the site ( after a Lot of picture has been uploaded) becomes too slow

1. how can i load photoes with php?(FTP)
2. how can i create new directory on a server with php?

Thanks to all for your future answers 
Have a nice day 
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a basic file input in HTML and the php function [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php) , example:

html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo"/>
</form>
```

php:

```
    $file= $_FILES['photo'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "/path/to/a/directory")){
        echo "yeah";
    }
```

If the /directory does not exist, it will create it for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. U can save the image's name in the database

here's a function i used to load jpeg images with a small size :

```
    function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);
         /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination with 100% quality*/
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest,100);
}   



        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $photoname = $row['imgTitle'];

        $source = "../images/big/".$photoname;

        $destination = "../images/thumb/thumb_".$photoname ."";         

        $width = "200";

        make_thumb($source,$destination,$width);
```

}